# What causes "A device which does not exist was specified" errors?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I recently moved from my old Windows 10 PC to a new one with Windows 11. Both computers had/have a number of external drives connected through a USB hub.

When I run a backup from one of the external disks to another one all goes well for some time, but then the destination disk seems to get disconnected, and I begin to get "A device which does not exist was specified" errors. The disk isn't accessible until I reboot.
I've never had this problem with my Win10 PC.

Any idea what causes this, and how to solve it? I've seen suggestions ranging from rebooting to replacing the hard disk. Needless to say that neither are satisfying.

---

Disks: WD Elements
USB hub: Anker USB 3.1
Backup software: SyncbackSE

(edit: more details, upon request from Robert):
MB chipset: Intel Tiger Point B560, Intel Comet Lake-S
CPU: Intel Core i5-10400
USB: Intel USB 3.20 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.20 (Microsoft)

Comment: You should be able to unplug the USB cable and plug it back in after 10 seconds. This should uninstall the device and install it again. Do not troubleshoot why you can't get the drive back after the disconnonect, but trouble the disconnect itself.

Comment: @LPChip -- Well, regarding the troubleshooting, I explicitely ask, both in the title and the body text, about the cause, don't I? Thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: What system are we talking about (system spec) and what chip/chipset does provide the used USB port(s)? May be it is a driver problem.

Comment: What format are the disks? NTFS?

Comment: @harrymc -- Yes, all my drives are NTFS. Note that the backup program not only did fine on the same disks under Win10, but also that the backup under Win11 goes fine up to a point, when errors pop up.

Comment: Are you using the latest SyncBackSE V10.1.24.0? Is it only one disk? If only one, run `chkdsk X: /f /r /x` and also check its SMART info.